# Display Python datetime without hours, minutes and seconds in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a date string and want to convert it to the date type:

I have tried to use `pd.to_datetime` with the format that I want but it is returning the time without the conversion.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2010-12-30 23:57:10+00:00', '2010-12-30 23:52:41+00:00','2010-12-30 23:43:04+00:00','2010-12-30 23:37:30+00:00','2010-12-30 23:31:39+00:00'],
    'text' : ['El odontólogo Barreda, a un paso de quedar en …','Defederico es el nuevo refuerzo de Independien..','Israel: ex presidente Katzav declarado culpabl…'
        , 'FMI estima que la recuperación asimétrica de l…','¿Quién fue el campeón argentino del año? Votá …']
}) 

df["new date"] =pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

That is the output that returns

`2010-12-30 23:57:10+00:00`

and I need to eliminate

`23:57:10+00:00` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's a date*time* object, so it needs to keep the time information. However, there's a Period datatype that might fit here: it represents a *span* of time instead of a *stamp*:

```py
df["new date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.to_period(freq="D")
```

which converts to *D*aily periods to get

```py
>>> df["new date"]

0    2010-12-30
1    2010-12-30
2    2010-12-30
3    2010-12-30
4    2010-12-30
Name: new date, dtype: period[D]
```

Noting that these are *not* strings; one can therefore continue to perform `.dt` based operations.

---

If you do need datetime type, though, you can `.normalize()` the timestamps to signal the time component is immaterial and they are all set to midnight:

```py
>>> df["new date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.normalize()
>>> df["new date"]

0   2010-12-30 00:00:00+00:00
1   2010-12-30 00:00:00+00:00
2   2010-12-30 00:00:00+00:00
3   2010-12-30 00:00:00+00:00
4   2010-12-30 00:00:00+00:00
Name: new date, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

Noting that after normalization, the display does not normally show that all-zero time information *if* the original datetime stamps do *not* have timezone information attached, i.e., the part after "+"; in your case, they do have it, so we see the zeros in the output as well. If you want to get rid of that in such cases, you can chain `.dt.tz_convert(tz=None)` to get rid of the timezone information and therefore the all-zeros in the output. Still, the output is of type datetime.

---

Lastly, if it is all about *display* purposes, then we can use `.strftime` to shape them into a desired format:

```py
>>> df["new date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
>>> df["new date"]

0    2010-12-30
1    2010-12-30
2    2010-12-30
3    2010-12-30
4    2010-12-30
Name: new date, dtype: object
```

As you see, the datatype is "object", i.e., string here, which would prevent datetime-based actions, e.g., `df["new date"].dt.month` would no longer work unlike the first two alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

To keep a DatetimeIndex and its `dt` accessor, you can use `dt.normalize()` to reset the time part then `dt.tz_convert` to remove the timezone information:

```
df['new date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.normalize().dt.tz_convert(None)
```

Output

```
>>> df['new date']
0   2010-12-30
1   2010-12-30
2   2010-12-30
3   2010-12-30
4   2010-12-30
Name: new date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```